# NHibernate is generating me incorrect indetity columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to generate some classes with Fluent NHibernate so I can have a code-first DB in SQLServer 2005, and something weird is happening. I'm mapping non-identity PKs, but somehow, NHibernate is translating it as Identity PKs.

This is my class:

```
    public class Job
{
    public virtual int JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Persons> People { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping for Job:

```
    public class JobMap : ClassMap<Job>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Table($"`{nameof(Job)}`");
        Id(j => j.JobId);

        HasMany(x => x.Tools).KeyColumn("JobId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        HasMany(x => x.People).KeyColumn("JobId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

And this is what the SchemaExport is throwing:

```
    create table [Job] (
    JobId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   primary key (JobId)
)
```

Creating the database:

```
        public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("JobsConnectionString").Get<string>();
        var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(() => FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ShowSql().UseReflectionOptimizer().ConnectionString(connectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<JobMap>())
            .BuildConfiguration();

        var exporter = new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(configuration);
        exporter.SetOutputFile(@"C:\Users\myself\Desktop\bbb.txt");
        exporter.Execute(true, true, false);

        var _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var isOpen = session.IsOpen;
        session.Close();
        _sessionFactory.Close();
    }
```

I have tried to remove the People and Tools mappings just in case something is wrong there, but doesn't seem to affect anything. And if I save a Job with a JobId, let's say, "23", it returns the object saved with Identity, "1" for example.

If I try to remove the identity thing from the sql generated and launch the create table in my db, when I try to save it gives me an error, like it seems that is saving JobId as null (since the engine thinks that the field is generated).

I'm using FluentNHibernate 3.0, by the way, and .Net Core 3.

Any hints to what is happening here? It also happens to other objects created.

Thanks.

EDIT: Creating a new project and trying to replicate the same thing with an object with only 2 properties (Id and Name, int and string), with the last version up to day of Fluent NH (3.1) and using SQL Server 2012 provider, the Schema Export keeps doing the same thing.

EDIT2: It's some error with Fluent Mapping, because creating the maps with XML, it works. I'm trying to debug it now.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using a version of SQL Server that has been end of life for the best part of **5 years**? Looks like NHibernate 3.0 has not been supported for *some* time as well as (according to this [github page](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Huge-Project,-Small-Team) support for version ends when the next major release is made available, and NHibernate 3.2 was released in 2011.

Comment: @Larnu Because it's not my call :)
Anyway, I'm trying with a new project with just a single object with two properties (Id and Name), and changing the provider to SQLServer2012, and nothing changes, it keeps creating the identity.

BTW, Fluent NHibernate 3, not NHibernate 3. In this version NH 5.2 is used, I think, and the last released version of Fluent NH is 3.1.

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't be surprised then if Nhibernate 5.2/Fluent NHibernate 3 don't support SQL Server 2005, as it had been end of life for almost 3 years when 5.2 came out.

Comment: I don't think it's that, since the last "provider" that Fluent NH has is the SQLS2012 one, and I tried it in a new project, and happened the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it was (as I supposed), nothing at all. The thing is that by default, the Ids in Fluent NH are generated, even if you don't want to. But we can change the generation mode, so we set it to "Assigned" to preserve the values passed, like it's stated in https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned

So at the end, the first mapping without the HasMany declarations ends being like

```
public class JobMap : ClassMap<Job>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Table($"`{nameof(Job)}`");
        Id(j => j.JobId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }
}
```